# Comparing and getting date from Laravel Eloquent Result

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, eloquent, laravel-5.5

This is the function inside my ReservationController:

```
public function realtime() {
    // Change to On Going
    $ongoing = Reservation::select('*') 
                            -> where('eventStatus', 'NYD') -> get();
    //dd($ongoing);
    foreach ($ongoing as $og) {
        echo "Started For Each\n";
        //dd($og);

        if ($og -> reservationStart > Carbon::now() && 
            $og -> reservationEnd < Carbon::now()) {
            $og -> eventStatus = "On Going";
            $og -> save();
            echo "Updated to ongoing!";
        }
        else {
            // echo $og -> reservationSTart;
        }

    }

    // Change to Done
}
```

This function is fired by a task scheduler. The task scheduler runs the command `php.exe {path/to/my}/artisan schedule:run`, and of course, the php.exe is added to the system variable PATH. The task is firing the command every minute. In my Kernel, I added this code inside my schedule function:

```
if (strtolower(env('SYS_REALTIME')) == "yes") {
        $schedule->call('App\Http\Controllers\ReservationController@realtime') -> everyMinute();
}
```

Now, everytime I fired the command (regardless if it is fired through manual schedule run or through task scheduler), I always get an error:

```
Running scheduled command: 
App\Http\Controllers\ReservationController@realtime
Started For Each


[InvalidArgumentException]
Unexpected data found.
Unexpected data found.
Data missing
```

I wanted the system to get the time from the query results, then compare it to the current time. If it is in-between the start and end time, I want to toggle the `eventStatus` value to `On Going`. Here are list of the fields in the database:

```
primeID - INT AI
reservationName - VARCHAR(30)
dateReserved - date
reservationStart - time
reservationEnd - time
```

So here's what I've tried so far:

- I tried using `dd()` to show values of `$ongoing`. It successfully displays the dump of everything regarding the variable (including date and time).
- I tried using `dd()` to show the value of `$og`. It successfully displays the dump of the variable passed including the date and time.
- I tried using `dd()` to display the value of `$og -> reservationStart`. Unexpected data found (just like the error I stated above). Also tried it in `reservationEnd`. Still, it throws an error.
- I tried using `dd()` to display the value of `$og -> dateReserved`. It displays the dump of the date correctly.
- I tried removing spaces between the variable and the member. Still I got an error. The same error.
- I tried removing all codes inside the `foreach` block except `echo "Started For Each\n";`. The loop runs successfully.
- I tried removing `get()` in my Laravel query. It didn't enter the loop.
- I tried removing `select('*')` in my Laravel query. Same error appears.
- I tried commenting the if statement and used `dd()` to display `$og -> reservationStart`. It throws the same error. Tried with `reservationEnd`, again, throws the same error.

What's wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already found the answer. In MySQL, date is trimmed when storing time. I simply changed the datatype to `datetime` and everything works fine.